# Custom form with php and ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I use a custom php image library which generate images and I need a script to update the functions when I select a color, font, size etc.

here i have all function taht i need to implement, but i need only a demo 
http://dev.template-tuners.com/makeaplate/

this is the code for my image

```
$imageLibObj = new imageLib('plate-yellow.png');
$imageLibObj -> addText(
    'YOUR REG', 
    $position = '85x21', 
    $padding = 0, 
    $fontColor = '#000', 
    $fontSize = 110, 
    $angle = 0, 
    $font = 'image_lib/fonts/UKNumberPlate.ttf'
);
$imageLibObj -> addWatermark('black-border.png', 'tr', 5, 0);
$imageLibObj -> addWatermark('blue-background-badge.png', '6 x 5', 0, 0);
$imageLibObj -> addWatermark('euro-gb.png', '14 x 24', 0, 0);
$imageLibObj -> addText('YOUR SLOGAN HERE', 
    $position = 'b', 
    $padding = 3, 
    $fontColor = '#ff0000', 
    $fontSize = 10, 
    $angle = 0
);
$imageLibObj -> saveImage('plate-demo.png', 100);
$imageLibObj->reset();
```

Any help please?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are you seeking for User Input capturing php code? (Do you wish to get the text the user filled-in and re-create the plate?)

Comment: You have two options, either:
reloading the page and using GET or POST to pull in the user's inputs
or
Making an AJAX call to the server and replacing the page content with the result... which do you require?

Comment: i want to use ajax to reload the image with new values when i choose another color, or when i write a text and click submit

Answer (score 0):

You can use a color picker and post it to your script.
JQuery has a color picker plugin (http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/) and there are many others...